# TextBoxFor not displaying value (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.hiddenfor

I got the following controls in my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Number)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number, new { disabled = "disabled" })
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.ID, Model.ProjectList, "Select", new { onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })
</div>
```

I submit the form when the dropdownlist value change to generate the Number field of the model, then the view is reloaded. When the is no HiddenFor control, the Number of the model is displayed properly in the TextBoxFor. When I add a HiddenFor control, the Number field is not displayed although Model.Number is not null.

What is the reason of this?

The reason why I want a HiddenFor with the Number value is that when I submit the form for saving, model.Number equals null. I thought by putting the value in a HiddenFor I would have access to it...

Edit: Controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateOpportunity(CreateEditOpportunityModel model)
    {
        // if the submit is made by the ddl
        if (model.SubmitValue.Equals("ChangeProject"))
        {
            Project parentProject = pCtx.Projects.Find(model.Project.ID);

            if (parentProject != null)
            {   
                // Generate the "Number field"
                Region projectRegion = rCtx.Regions.Find(parentProject.RegionID);
                int numOpportunity = oCtx.Opportunitites.Count(o => o.ProjectID == parentProject.ID);
                numOpportunity++;
                string oppNumber = numOpportunity < 10 ? "0" + numOpportunity : numOpportunity.ToString();
                model.Number = projectRegion.Name + "-" + parentProject.ID + "-" + oppNumber;



            }

            // Repopulate the ddl
            model.ProjectList = new SelectList(pCtx.Projects, "ID", "ID");

            return View(model);
        }

        // if submit is made by the save button
        else if (model.SubmitValue.Equals("CreateOpportunity"))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity();
                opportunity.ID = model.ID;
                opportunity.Number = model.Number;
                opportunity.ActivationDate = model.ActivationDate;
                opportunity.Assignee = model.Assignee;
                opportunity.Comments = model.Comments;
                opportunity.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                opportunity.LicenseFilePath = model.LicenseFilePath;
                opportunity.LicenseRequestFilePath = model.LicenseRequestFilePath;
                opportunity.OkPermanentStatus = model.OkPermanentStatus;
                opportunity.PaidStatus = model.PaidStatus;
                opportunity.PartNumber = model.PartNumber;
                opportunity.Project = pCtx.Projects.Find(model.Project.ID);

                //tell EF that Project already exists in Company table
                oCtx.Entry(opportunity.Project).State = EntityState.Modified;

                // Saves project
                oCtx.Opportunitites.Add(opportunity);
                oCtx.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            model.ProjectList = new SelectList(pCtx.Projects, "ID", "ID");

            return View(model);
        }

        model.ProjectList = new SelectList(pCtx.Projects, "ID", "ID");

        return View(model);
    }
```

This part of the code works fine, I'm just putting it here to clarify things.

Comment: To clarify - the dropdown element is being used to supply a value for the `Number` property by making a full request back to the server when the value changes, and repopulating the same view with all of the same data and in addition, a value for the `Number` property. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. The project id generate the "Number" value, as an example "NAM-1-01" (Project Region - Project ID - sequential number). I could post my controller method if you want but I thought the issue is not there...

Comment: Ok. Do you **need** to show the value of the `Number` property before the model is persisted somewhere? It *feels* like you'd only need it once the model is persisted...

Comment: I need to show it when a project is selected in the ddl, which work, but when I save, it seems a TextBoxFor that is disabled doesn't save the value in the model, thus my HiddenFor idea which created the display problem. Sorry my first language is french so I have difficulty grasping some english terms sometimes. Not sure what you mean by "persisted"...

Comment: My question is why are you reloading the view? This is how I would handle it...On the ddl change event fire an AJAX request to the controller to generate the number. When that request returns set the value of `tbFor/hiddenFor` to the value that Ajax request returned. I can show you in code what I mean.

Comment: I know nothing of Ajax requests but if it can access the controller objects (database contexts) then it would be a good solution. Yes, a code example would be greatly appreciated. In the meanwhile, I'll read on ajax requests in MVC4.